# Morning or evening exercise?

Tags: performance, timing

I looked up which is better and Google seems to give plenty articles supporting either.

I'm guessing it depends on the person's work/study schedule, being fat or not, type of exercise, exercise goals, etc.

What are some factors to consider as to when one should exercise, assuming work/study schedule is sufficiently flexible?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have know medical problems (especially cardiac) you may exercise in the morning. This also make you burn more calories during the day. However, if you have cardiovascular problems you may prefer doing exercise in the late afternoon, since testosterone hormone secreted early in the morning that may cause some heart beat abnormalities and can give you hard time.

Comment: "testosterone hormone secreted early in the morning that may cause some heart beat abnormalities " got any scientific studies/biology texts backing that claim?

Comment: There are many. If you search for "high testosterone heart attack" you will get lots of results.

Comment: @bantandor It's not incumbent upon us to search for a claim you make.  If there are studies, you should reference them.  Telling someone to search for themselves is not helpful.

Comment: I just gave the idea to help people where to start from. This way they will learn more. "do not give me fish teach me how to fish"

Comment: @bantandor looks like you do not understand how SE is designed to work: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: May be I don't, but I know how the education is designed. By the way, you can also check my previous posts and then you decide if I know how SE is designed to work.

Comment: @bantandor - JJ is correct. You are expected to provide the references for claims that you make.